# regarding sending mail to user

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("admin@mysite.com");
```

Now for fetching email entered by the user in the textbox, I wrote:-

```
 message.To.Add(Convert.ToString(txtEmail));
```

but this is not working..isn't this the correct way to add email address in "To" ?
txtEmail is the textbox's name..Its not giving any error or something..just not working..when I comment out this line of code..the code line next to it works..otherwise code stops working when it encounters this "To.Add " method..plz help..thnx

***[edit]
I changed it to***

```
message.To.Add(txtEmail.ToString());
```

still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txtEmail.Text
```

should work.

Try to make it

```
message.To.Add(txtEmail.Text);
```